# concurrent hashmap and copyonwritearraylist

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap, copyonwritearraylist

I am trying to populate a cache which hold the key/value with ConcurrentHashMap.

I am assuming using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` takes care of concurrency and I have that as my value for my key, but I am missing something in the below code and it is overriding its values when multiple threads are executing.

```
if (testMap.get(id) == null) {
   CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> copyArr = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
   copyArr.add("Add Value");
   testMap().putIfAbsent(id, copyArr);
} else {                    
   testMap.put(id,testMap.get().add("Append Value"));
}
```

How do I protect the code which creates the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` from multiple threads.

**Here is the revised version of code as per the suggestions below.**

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Subscriber> subscriberArr =  CacheUtils.getSubscriberMap().get(syncDet.getCardNumber());

if (subscriberArr == null) {

subscriberArr = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Subscriber>();
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Subscriber> refArr = 

cacheUtils.getSubscriberMap().putIfAbsent(syncDet.getCardNumber(), subscriberArr);

if (refArr != null) {
 subscriberArr = refArr;
}

}
 subscriberArr.add(syncDet.getSubScriber());
```

On iterating the subscriber map i dont see a value object. size is 0 .

Comment: Read the first sentence of the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) - it's not a magic drop-in replacement, there's a catch. More importantly, why are you not writing to your `ConcurrentHashMap` directly? The way you wrote your code actually removes the advantage of using `putIfAbsent`, which does exactly what your `if`, but in a thread-safe way.

Comment: I need to check if an arraylist is already exisiting for that id. if it exists i have to add my value to it.

Comment: So you need a multimap then? Alright, I'll try to write up an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first retrieve the appropriate list then populate it. Something like:

```
List<String> copyArr = testMap.get(id);
if (copyArr == null) {
    copyArr = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
    List<String> inMap = testMap.putIfAbsent(id, copyArr);
    if (inMap != null) copyArr = inMap; // already in map
}
copyArr.add("Add Value");
```

That way you only put a new list in the map if there wasn't already one and you add your item to whatever list has made it to the map.

Comment: hi assyilas, should there be a map.replace(id,copyArr) at the end

Comment: @user2596957 Why? `copyArr` is a reference that points to the list that is in the map - so whatever operations you apply to `copyArr` are performed on the list within the map.

Comment: i have taken the above code and implemented my dev version as below.

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList<Subscriber> subscriberArr = CacheUtils      .getSubscriberMap().get(syncDet.getCardNumber());

if (subscriberArr == null) {

subscriberArr = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Subscriber>();
     CopyOnWriteArrayList<Subscriber> refArr = CacheUtils       .getSubscriberMap().putIfAbsent(         syncDet.getCardNumber(), subscriberArr);

if (refArr != null) {
subscriberArr = refArr;
}

}
    subscriberArr.add(syncDet.getSubScriber());

Comment: No .updated the same code above. do you see any issues with that code?

Comment: @user2596957 What doesn't work? Are you sure that `syncDet.getCardNumber()` does not change during the execution? You should try to create a simple example that reproduces the issue (i.e. I can copy paste it and see that it does not work) and post it in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the implementation you made.

*Firstly*, you are checking whether there is no list for a given key in a non-thread-safe way. It can entirely happen that two threads can execute `if (testMap.get(id) == null)` **before** any of them puts the key. This will not cause the key to be overriden per se.

However, **both** lists are generated, and since you're adding elements to those lists in the unsafe `if` block **prior to the setting of the key**, what elements wind up in the actual key->value mapping is anyone's guess.

Also, there's absolutely no need for this:

```
testMap.put(id,testMap.get(id).add("Append Value"));
```

The list instance is already in the map in this case, you just need to `get` it and add the value. Note that this may also mess up your previous key assignment!

---

The *second*, potential problem is that you're using a `CopyOnWriteList` which creates a new backing array on adding new elements. Two consequences here:

- it's expensive if there are a lot of additions.
- since the `add` operation is synchronized (through a `ReentrantLock`), but `get` **isn't**, you may get **different list contents in different threads for a short time** (the list is **eventually consistent for addition**, however). This is actually by design - `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is geared towards hi-read/lo-write operations.

You've got at least two ways out here:

- conduct `put` operations in a thread-safe manner, i.e.

  - use only `putIfAbsent`.
  - don't add any values to the local copy of the list, just the one you take from `get`.
- if you need absolute instead of eventual consistency, don't use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` at all. Use a normal list with "manual" synchronization instead. You can use e.g. Guava's Multimap's, such [as this one](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html), with a synchronization wrapper to save you the trouble (the Javadoc explains how).

Comment: Although your comments make sense there is no need for extra synchronisation to make it work. It is only a matter of using the value returned by putIfAbsent.

Comment: @assylias : there is if the OP needs absolute consistency, and foregoes using `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. But I guess you mean the first point, in which the word "synchronize" is potentially ambiguous. I'll edit the wording to avoid confusion, thanks.

Comment: Thanks TheTerribleSwiftTomato for highlighting the mistake of not using the using the return object from putIfAbsent. Problem is resolved.

Comment: @user2596957 : you're welcome. Please [accept one of the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/229328) (whichever helped you the most) in order for this question to be marked as solved.